# Binding to a property doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

this is the Code behind of user control

```
 public delegate void YardSelectionChangedDelegate();
 public event YardSelectionChangedDelegate YardSelectionChanged;
 public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedYardIdProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
         "SelectedYardId",
         typeof(long),
         typeof(YardSelectorUserControl),
         new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

And this is the Property:

```
public long SelectedYardId
{
    get { return (long)GetValue(SelectedYardIdProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedYardIdProperty, value); }
}
```

And this is the Binding in the parent window:

```
SelectedYardId="{Binding  Path=YardId,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

The problem is that the Set of the property never work and cursor never reach the Set body.
thanks indeed.

Comment: can you show us the YardId implementation? look at the output window for any BindingExpression warnings or errors. sometimes you ca see what's wrong with your binding.

Comment: public long YardId { get { return 46; }}

Comment: thanks for reply but nothing got yet...

Comment: you are binding to `YardId`, but showing us the code of `SelectedYardId` ... is that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because binding engine doesn't use your set or get accessors for setting or getting a property. It uses SetValue and GetValue of the DependencyObject directly. In order to trigger an event while changing a dependency property you need to define a callback delegate while registering your dependency property like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedYardIdProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedYardId",
        typeof(long),
        typeof(YardSelectorUserControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(OnSelectedYardIdChanged));

public static void OnSelectedYardIdChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     // Action 
}
```

Comment: I tried tthat but as the callback delegate is Static i can't edit any non static varables...

Comment: you can edit the sender : (sender as YardSelectorUserControl).myProperty = someValue;

Comment: That is why there is a "Sender" parameter in the callback method. It is a reference to your dependencyObject which in this case is YardSelectorUserControl.    `(sender as YardSelectorUserControl).YourInstanceMember = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your model, and change "YardId" property to raise PropertyChanged event in the "Set" body.